# python: pretty print deeply nested braces in string (mastermind game)

Tags: python, nested, text-parsing

Here is a long string that is deeply nested...

```
{HHCAA:{00:GGEDB:{00:FFFFF,01:DFDFF:{...
```

Please see this link for the full string >>>
[mastermind github string](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BobGenom/7cef941fa64f977f2aa2/raw/236e89b6348d843d8c3d28c9e14e3820f14ffaa2/ppcg-mastermind-5-8)

This string is in relation to this original question >>> [Mastermind Strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31926/mastermind-strategy/35296#35296?newreg=01602318b7544a0cae28524442a1ce2e)

How to pretty print the string so that we can follow through to the end and make it a lookup table... e.g. I want to find the first `00, 01, 02, 03 and so on...`

Please see some extract below:

`{HHCAA:
  {00:GGEDB:{00:FFFFF,01:xxxx...}}}},
   01:DCDCB:{00:EEHFF:xxxx
   02:xxxx
   03:xxxx`

The first nested brace printed in column 1, indent it say 5 spaces for the next one, then indent again.. then come back to column 1 again.. and start indenting again, etc. or make it tabular.

Comment: Try `import pprint; pprint.pprint(data)`

Comment: tried that (now).. but that doesn't really indent for me.. may be i do it wrong?  ```'{HHCAA:{00:GGEDB:{00:FFFFF,01:``` (still prints in same style)

Answer (score 0):

Python's standard pretty-printing tools will create indented, multi-line output for nested objects, but not for strings, as there is no way to know in advance what represents nesting in your "deeply-nested" string.

Assuming that curly braces (`{`, `}`) are the delimiters that define your nesting you have two options:

1. Convert your string into a python dictionary and use `pprint.pprint`
2. Write you own tool to parse the string and generate the output.  If you are only interested in curly braces you just need to maintain a counter that tracks the nesting level, incrementing for `{` and decrementing for `}`.  This let you compute the indentation required at any time.  You will need to add some logic if, as in your example, you don't always move to a new line when you find a `{`.

Comment: thank you for your input. i managed to use ```pyparsing``` module and ```pprint``` together with gvim (vi) to get what i want. (part auto and part manual). I will share my solution here after making improvements. sample pyparsing code: ```t1 = pp.nestedExpr(opener='{', closer='}').parseString(mytext);  lst_t1 = t1.asList();  pprint.pprint(lst_t1, indent=4)``` then reverted to gvim for visualize the indents and search using indent pattern matching.